# How to make a filter/remove like function to remove instances of an integer in a list by using a reduce function only in python

Tags: python, filter, reduce

**Hey I am pretty new to python and self learning it for me to eventually be somewhat decent in my coding skill i have got an idea of using map/filter/reduce functions. I am trying a challenge friend gave me to remove and element from list using remove filter and reduce**

here is my code for filter

```
def removeall_ft(item, test_list):
 
    res = list(filter(lambda x: x!=item, test_list))
    return res
print(removeall_ft(0, [1,0,1]))
it gives [1,1]
```

working great

import functools

```
def removeall_rd(item, test_list):

    res = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x if y!=item else x, test_list)
    return res

print(removeall_ft(0, [1,0,1]))
```

but this doesnt give me desired answer any help is appreciated

Comment: `reduce` is not the right tool for filtering an iterable. Of course, you could build up a new iterable using it, something like `reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + ([x] if x == item else []), [1,0,1], [])` but that is really not a good way to do this.

Comment: Yeah you are right its not the best way but i was trying to understand the reduce concept and have some experiments for self learning btw thank you i understood it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

functools.reduce returns a new(or mutated) object

```
def reduce_step(return_so_far,this_value):
    if this_value !=item:
       return [*return_so_far,this_value]
    return return_so_far
```

it takes a method to reduce, a target list, and an optional initial_value for the result (`return_so_far`)

```
item = 4
result = reduce(reduce_step,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[])
print(result)
```

as mentioned in the comments this is not a very good way to filter a list